# How do I set up indexes so that a search on concatenated fields use the index and not a full table scan

Tags: mysql

I have a names table, with id, first_name, last_name.

I need to give the user the ability to search, based on combinations of first and last name with a space in between.

SELECT * from names WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%john adam%';

This is what I need and it works perfectly, except that the explain shows that it is not using any indexes and as the table grows the search takes longer.

PK is id.

I tried an index on first_name, last_name together,

and an index on first_name and index on last_name.

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem with `first_name = 'john' and last_name = 'adam'`?

Comment: thanks. That would change the ui and require the user to decide what is in first and last name fields. The way I have it, a search of "Jane Patrick Murdock" will return the result no matter if 'Patrick' is in the first_name or last_name. Also, based on that one search box I look up other fields -WHERE (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%search%') OR contact_company LIKE '%search%';

Comment: Perhaps you want to investigate [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html)?